# When I push my code in Github then remote permission error comes in Ubuntu

Tags: git, github, push

When I push my code in Github then a remote Permission Error comes in Ubuntu.
I Want to push my code in my Github repository but this error comes

```
hamza@hamza-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/chat-website$ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/hamza/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/chat-website/.git/
hamza@hamza-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/chat-website$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is based on 'origin/main', but the upstream is gone.
  (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
hamza@hamza-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/chat-website$ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/hamza/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/chat-website/.git/
hamza@hamza-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/chat-website$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is based on 'origin/main', but the upstream is gone.
  (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
hamza@hamza-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/chat-website$ git add .
hamza@hamza-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/chat-website$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is based on 'origin/main', but the upstream is gone.
  (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
hamza@hamza-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/chat-website$ git push -u origin main
remote: Permission to hamzaabialal/chat-website.git denied to hamzbialal.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/hamzaabialal/chat-website.git/': The requested URL returned errorlike so
: 403
hamza@hamza-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/chat-website$
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlIFN.png)

Comment: "*Permission to **hamzaabialal** /chat-website.git denied to **hamzbialal**.*"

Comment: I wonder why you're calling git inside an existing git repository. Also, why are you adding images of text in your question? Use text instead. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue you can do any of the following:

1. Add a default Host matching the remote URL;
2. Setting remote URL using git remote set-url Command;
3. Update the `.git/config` file to one of the URLs in the Host.